# Taking the derivative of the following integral

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

I have the following double integral which I want to differentiate one times with respect to $1$. Or simply I want to obtain $h'(1)$.

$h(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\int_{0}^{x} f(u,v)du dv$

The following answer has been provided.

$\int_{0}^{1}(f(1,t)+f(t,1))dt$

I am not able to understand how this has been obtained. Although, I know how to take derivative of the integral when only one integral is provided. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "differentiate one times with respect to $1$"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$h(x)=H(x,x)$$
where
$$H(x,y)=\int_0^x\!\!\int_0^y f(u,v)\,du\,dv.$$
By the chain rule,
$$h'(1)=H_1(1,1)+H_2(1,1)$$
where $H_1(x,y)$ is the partial derivative of $H$ with respect
to its first argument and $H_2(x,y)$ is the partial derivative of $H$ with respect
to its second argument. Then
$$H_1(x,y)=\int_0^y f(x,v)\,dv$$
and so
$$H_1(1,1)=\int_0^1 f(1,t)\,dt.$$
Likewise
$$H_2(1,1)=\int_0^1 f(t,1)\,dt.$$